# Query works in phpMyAdmin, but not in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

If I write the following query in phpmyadmin, it runs and returns the correct result

```
select `u`.*, count(t.empid) as totalassignedtask from `users` as `u` left join `tasks` as `t` on `t`.`empid` = `u`.`id` where `u`.`role` = 'user' group by `t`.`empid`
```

However, if I wrote this query in laravel like this

```
$allemp = DB::table('users as u')
                        ->leftJoin('tasks as t','t.empid','=','u.id')
                        ->where('u.role','=','user')
                        ->select('u.*',DB::raw('count(t.empid) as totalassignedtask'))
                        ->groupBy('t.empid')
                        ->get();
```

I get an error:

> Illuminate \ Database \ QueryException (42000)
>   SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'employee.u.id' isn't in GROUP BY (SQL: select `u`.*, count(t.empid) as totalassignedtask from `tasks` as `t` left join `users` as `u` on `t`.`empid` = `u`.`id` where `u`.`role` = user group by `t`.`empid`)

Answer (score 3):

This is may be SQL_MODE problem.

In your config/database.php, in the connection, change mysql

```
strict => false
```

Answer (score 1):

In config/database.php at "mysql" change :

```
'strict' => true,
```

to false.
Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for answer - I changed the column name in code and it works

```
$allemp = DB::table('users as u')
                        ->join('tasks as t','t.empid','=','u.id')
                        ->where('u.role','=','user')
                        ->select('u.id','u.name','u.email',DB::raw('count(t.empid) as totalassignedtask'))
                        ->groupBy('u.id','u.name','u.email')
                        ->orderBy('totalassignedtask', 'asc')
                        ->get();
```